# Toggle in the PDF

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to create a toggle in the PDF (or other output formats) generated by LaTeX?

I mean something like this figure:

[image]

If you click on the arrow, you can read more

[image]

Comment: In PDF, you can make content optional using OCGs, vulgo PDF Layers. Note however, that folding of content acc. to its current visibility is not possible due to the paginated nature of PDF; content is distributed over the document pages during typesetting and its position is immutable afterwards. You can make PDF Layers with the `ocgx2` package.

Comment: @AlexG Wow, `ocgx2` is nice. Consider converting your comment into an answer (sorry, I don't know if the example given in my answer uses the same package [indirectly] or not).

Comment: Oh, it actually uses ocgx2 directly!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

A solution based on the `ocgx2` package that mimics the example in the question. It defines the command `\itemtoggle` which takes two arguments and which is to be used in the optional argument of `\item` in an itemized list:

```
\item[\itemtoggle{<layer name>}{<internal id>}]
```

It inserts a rotating, clickable triangle as item symbol and creates a new, initially hidden PDF layer (OCG). `<layer name>` is shown in the PDF viewer's Layers tab, `<internal id>` is used to reference the layer within the document source.

Additional text below the item can then be made optional by means of `<internal id>` and an `ocmd` environment:

```
\begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{<internal id>}}
   Additional information ...
\end{ocmd}
```

An OCMD is another kind of PDF layer whose visibility is not set directly by the user (it has no name and is not accessible in the viewer's Layers Tab) but depends on the visibility of OCG layers in the document according to a [policy or boolean expression](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/ocgx2#the-ocmd-environment-optional-content-membership-dictionary).

---

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathabx} % \blacktriangleright, \blacktriangledown

\usepackage{ocgx2}

% toggle switch with rotating item symbol; also defines Layer name and id
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemtoggle}{mm}{% #1 OCG name (as shown in Layer tab of the PDF viewer);
                                     % #2 internal identifier
  {\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}% suppresses link border around item if hyperref is loaded
  \switchocg{#2}{%           
    \begin{ocg}{#1}{#2}{off}\rlap{$\blacktriangledown$}\end{ocg}%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{#2}}$\blacktriangleright$\end{ocmd}%
  }}%
}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\hypersetup}{m}{}

\begin{document}
The relativity equation $E=mc^2$
\begin{itemize}
\item[\itemtoggle{Mass-Energy Equivalence}{emc2}] 
  {\color{cyan}%
  In physics, mass-energy equivalence is the relationship between mass and energy in a system's rest frame, where the two values differ only by a constant and the units of measurement. The principle is described by Albert Einstein's famous formula.}

  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{emc2}}
  The formula defines the Energy ($E$) of a particle in its rest frame as the product of mass ($m$) and speed of light squared ($c^2$) \dots
  \end{ocmd}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice show...`+1`

Answer (score 4):

This is actually possible. See [this](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Emoyen/Hypertext_proof/) example.

[This](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Emoyen/Hypertext_proof/hypertext_proof.pdf) is a sample pdf file and [here](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Emoyen/Hypertext_proof/hypertext_proof.tex) is its latex code.

A caveat is that when content is hidden, white space will appear there (See page 3, 'click me' text in orange colour in [this file](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Emoyen/Hypertext_proof/hypertext_proof.pdf)).

Also, not all pdf viewer support this type of features (many do).

A part of code from the above link is pasted below (just in case the link gets dead in future)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{pf2} % annoying conflict with amsthm on environment proof
                 % renamed to structproof.
\beforePfSpace{0pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{hyperref} % do NOT set [ocgcolorlinks] here!
\usepackage[tikz,ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.callouts, shapes.symbols}

% Colourblind friendly colours
% http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/#pallet
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{230,159,0}
\definecolor{skyblue}{RGB}{86,180,230} % light blue
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,158,115} % blueish green
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{240,228,66}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,114,178}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{213,94,0} % vermillon
\definecolor{pink}{RGB}{204,121,167} % reddish purple



%%% OCG handling commands
% #1: OCG name, #2: OCG refname, #3: OCG visibility, #4: colour
% \newcommand{\ocguline}[4]{\bgroup\markoverwith
%   {\begin{ocg}{#1}{#2}{#3}\textcolor{#4}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}\end{ocg}}\ULon}

\newcommand{\ocghline}[4]{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\begin{ocg}{#1}{#2}{#3}\textcolor{#4}{\rule[-0.65ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}\end{ocg}}\ULon}
\newcommand{\largeocghline}[4]{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\begin{ocg}{#1}{#2}{#3}\textcolor{#4}{\rule[-0.75ex]{.1pt}{3.2ex}}\end{ocg}}\ULon}

%   We cannot put the OCGs in a radio button group because the
%   \switchocg acts on each OCG in order of the list. When the off OCG
%   is turned on, the radio button group automatically turn off the
%   other, but then the \switchocg acts on it… and turn it on again!

% #1: OCG name, #2: OCG refname, #3: colour
\newcommand{\jymulhl}[3]{\bgroup%
  \markoverwith{%
    \rlap{%
      \begin{ocg}{#1HL}{#2hl}{off}%
        \textcolor{#3!50}{\rule[-0.65ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}%
      \end{ocg}}%
    \begin{ocg}{#1UL}{#2ul}{on}%
      \textcolor{#3}{\rule[-0.5ex]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}%
    \end{ocg}}\ULon}

% TikZ anchors in the text need to be \hbox-ed to allow the
% underlining to work correctly.
\newcommand{\jymanchor}[1]{%
  \hbox{\tikz[remember picture]{\coordinate (anchor#1);}}}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\Large Hypertext proofs}\\
  Jean-Yves Moyen
\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
  Using Optional Contents Group to hide and show parts of texts and to
  structure proofs (following some of L.~Lamport's
  ideas~\cite{LamportProof} and creating hypertext proofs).
\end{abstract}

In \cite{LamportProof}, L.~Lamport advocates the use of ``Structured
proofs'' instead of ``prose proofs'' in order to write 21\textup{th}
century mathematical proofs.

\vdots

The ``case of study'' proof that I use is the same as the one used by
Lamport, taken from M.~Spivak's calculus book~\cite{Spivak}.

\vdots
(skipped proof from Spivak)

\section{Lamport's structured proof}
\label{sec:lamport-proof}
I give here the formulation (naming the interval) and proof of
Corollary~\ref{cor:spivak} given by Lamport. The structured proof is
typeset using Lamport's \texttt{pf2} package\footnote{
  \url{http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/latex/latex.html},
  the package redefines a \texttt{proof} environment which I have
  renamed as \texttt{structproof} to avoid conflict with the one from
  the \texttt{amsthm} package\ldots}.

\begin{corollary}
  \label{cor:lamport}
  If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in an interval $I$, then $f$ is
  increasing on $I$.
\end{corollary}

\pflongnumbers

\begin{proof}[Lamport's Proof]~\\[-.5cm]
  \begin{structproof}
    \step{1}{It suffices to assume
      \begin{pfenum*}
      \item $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$
      \item $a < b$
      \end{pfenum*}
      and prove $f(b) > f(a)$.
    }
    \begin{structproof}
      \pf\ By definition of an increasing function.
    \end{structproof}
    \step{2}{There is some $x$ in $]a;b[$ with $f'(x) = \frac{f(b) -
        f(a)}{b-a}$.}
    \begin{structproof}
      \step{2.1}{$f$ is differentiable on $[a;b]$.}
      \begin{structproof}
        \pf\ By 1.1, since $f$ is differentiable on $I$ by
        hypothesis.
      \end{structproof}
      \step{2.2}{$f$ is continuous on $[a;b]$.}
      \begin{structproof}
        \pf\ By \stepref{2.1} and Theorem~\ref{thm:diff-cont}.
      \end{structproof}
      \qedstep
      \begin{structproof}
        \pf\ By \stepref{2.1}, \stepref{2.2}, and the Mean Value
        Theorem (Theorem~\ref{thm:mean-value}).
      \end{structproof}
    \end{structproof}
    \step{3}{$f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $]a;b[$.}
    \begin{structproof}
      \pf\ By the hypothesis of the corollary and assumption 1.1
    \end{structproof}
    \step{4}{$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} > 0$.}
    \begin{structproof}
      \pf\ By \stepref{2} and \stepref{3}.
    \end{structproof}
    \qedstep
    \begin{structproof}
      \pf\ Assumption 1.2 implies $b-a>0$, so \stepref{4} implies
      $f(b)-f(b) > 0$, which implies $f(b) > f(a)$. By \stepref{1}, this
      proves the corollary.
    \end{structproof}
  \end{structproof}
\end{proof}

\newpage
\section{Hypertext prose proof}
\begin{corollary}
  \label{cor:jym}
  % some slanted/italic letters go out of their bounding box and a \,
  % must be added to avoid the highlight of the space to 'eat' the
  % letter.
  If \ocghline{f' positive
    HL}{derposhl}{off}{orange}{$f'(x) > 0$\jymanchor{derposhyp} for\,
    all\, $x$ in an interval\, $I$}, then $f$ is increasing on $I$.
\end{corollary}

\begin{proof}[Hypertext prose proof]
  \switchocg{increasingul
    increasinghl}{\jymulhl{Increasing}{increasing}{green}{Let us
      consider any two points in $I$, $a$ and $b$ , with $a < b$
      and\jymanchor{increasing} show $f(a) < f(b)$.}}\\
  \jymanchor{exists}There exists some $x$ in $]a;b[$ with
  \[
  f'(x) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}.
  \]
  \jymanchor{mean}But \switchocg{derposul derposhl}{\jymulhl{f'
      positive}{derpos}{orange}{$f'(x) > 0$\jymanchor{derposused} for
      all $x$ in $]a;b[$}}, so
  \[
  \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} > 0.
  \]
  \jymanchor{concl}Since $b-a>0$ it follows that $f(b)>f(a)$.
\end{proof}

% Extra decorations
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[blue, line width=.3ex] ($(anchorexists) + (-0.2ex,2ex)$) --
  ($(anchormean) + (-0.2ex,2.3ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

% OCGs
% a<b sufficient
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Increasing
    proof, ref=increasinghl, status=invisible}]
  \coordinate (anchorcallout) at ($(anchorincreasing) + (0,1.5ex)$);

  \node[draw=green, fill=green!20, rectangle callout, rounded corners,
  callout absolute pointer=(anchorcallout), text width=5cm, inner
  sep=1ex]
  (increasingexplanation) at ($(anchorincreasing) + (-0.5,1.8)$) {By
    definition of an increasing function, this suffices to prove the
    result.};

  \coordinate (innernw) at ($(increasingexplanation.north west) +
  (0.1,-0.1)$);
  \coordinate (innersw) at ($(increasingexplanation.south west) +
  (0.1,0.1)$);
  \coordinate (innerne) at ($(increasingexplanation.north east) +
  (-0.1,-0.1)$);
  \coordinate (innerse) at ($(increasingexplanation.south east) +
  (-0.1,0.1)$);
  \coordinate (inneranchor) at ($(innernw)!0.6!(innersw)$);

  \draw[red, line width=.3ex] (innernw) -- (innersw);

  \path[switch ocg={nested1}] (innersw) rectangle (innerne);

  \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Expanding def, ref=nested1,
      status=invisible}]
    \draw[red, line width=.3ex] (innersw) rectangle (innerne);

    \node[draw=red, fill=red!30, rectangle callout, rounded corners,
    callout absolute pointer=(inneranchor), text width = 7cm] at
    ($(inneranchor) + (-4,1)$) {By Definition~\ref{def:increasing},
      $f$ is increasing on $I$ iff $\forall a, b \in I$ with $a < b$,
      we have $f(a) < f(b)$. Thus, to prove that $f$ is increasing on
      $I$, it is sufficient to consider any two $a$ and $b$ in $I$
      with $a < b$ and show $f(a) < f(b)$.};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% button for the MVT application
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (existssw) at ($(anchormean) + (-0.2ex,2.3ex)$);
  \coordinate (existsne) at ($(anchorexists) + (9.6cm,2ex)$);
  \path[switch ocg={existshl}] (existssw) rectangle (existsne);
\end{tikzpicture}

% MVT details.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Exists HL,
    ref=existshl, status=invisible}]

  \coordinate (existscallout) at ($(existsne) + (0,-0.2cm)$);

  \fill[blue, opacity=.2] (existssw) rectangle (existsne);

  \node[draw=blue, fill=blue!20, rectangle callout, rounded corners,
  callout absolute pointer=(existscallout), text width=5cm, inner
  sep=1ex] (existsexplanation) at ($(existscallout) + (3cm, -0.5cm)$)
  {By the Mean Value Theorem (Theorem~\ref{thm:mean-value}).};

  \coordinate (mvtnw) at ($(existsexplanation.north west) +
  (0.1,-0.1)$);
  \coordinate (mvtsw) at ($(existsexplanation.south west) +
  (0.1,0.1)$);
  \coordinate (mvtne) at ($(existsexplanation.north east) +
  (-0.1,-0.1)$);
  \coordinate (mvtse) at ($(existsexplanation.south east) +
  (-0.1,0.1)$);
  \coordinate (mvtanchor) at ($(mvtnw)!0.6!(mvtne)$);

  \draw[red, line width=.3ex] (mvtnw) -- (mvtsw);

  \path[switch ocg={mvtshort}] (mvtsw) rectangle (mvtne);
  \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Mean Value, ref=mvtshort, status=invisible}]
    \draw[red, line width=.3ex] (mvtsw) rectangle (mvtne);

    \node[draw=red, fill=red!30, rectangle callout, rounded corners,
    callout absolute pointer=(mvtanchor), text width = 6cm] at
    ($(mvtanchor) + (-0.5,2)$)
    {\textcolor{pink}{$\bullet$}\jymanchor{diffclose}%
      \switchocg{diffclose}{\ocghline{Foo}{diffclose}{off}{pink!20}{$f$
          is differentiable on $[a;b]$.}}\\
      \textcolor{pink}{$\bullet$}\jymanchor{diffopen}%
      \switchocg{diffopen}{\ocghline{Foo}{diffopen}{off}{pink!20}{$f$
          is differentiable on $]a;b[$.}}\\
      \textcolor{pink}{$\bullet$}\jymanchor{cont}%
      \switchocg{cont}{\ocghline{Foo}{cont}{off}{pink!20}{$f$
          is continuous on $[a;b]$.}}\\
      Therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem
      (Theorem~\ref{thm:mean-value}), there exists such an $x$.};

    \coordinate (calloutdiffclose) at ($(anchordiffclose) + (-1ex,0.7ex)$);
    \coordinate (calloutdiffopen) at ($(anchordiffopen) + (-1ex,0.7ex)$);
    \coordinate (calloutcont) at ($(anchorcont) + (-1ex,0.7ex)$);

    \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Differentiable on close, ref=diffclose,
        status=invisible}]
      \node[draw=pink, fill=pink!20, rectangle callout, rounded
      corners, callout absolute pointer=(calloutdiffclose), text
      width=8cm] at ($(anchordiffclose) + (-5cm, 1.2cm)$) {Because
        $[a;b] \subset I$ and $f$ is differentiable on $I$ by
        hypothesis.};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Differentiable on open, ref=diffopen,
        status=invisible}]
      \node[draw=pink, fill=pink!20, rectangle callout, rounded
      corners, callout absolute pointer=(calloutdiffopen), text
      width=8cm] at ($(anchordiffopen) + (-5cm, 0.15cm)$) {Because
        $]a;b[ \subset I$ and $f$ is differentiable on $I$ by
        hypothesis.};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Continuous, ref=cont,
        status=invisible}]
      \node[draw=pink, fill=pink!20, rectangle callout, rounded
      corners, callout absolute pointer=(calloutcont), text width=8cm]
      at ($(anchorcont) + (-5cm, -0.9cm)$) {Because $f$ is
        differentiable on $[a;b]$ by the previous points, thus it is
        continuous on $[a;b]$ by Theorem~\ref{thm:diff-cont}.};
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% f' positive by hypothesis.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=f' positive HL,
    ref=derposhl, status=invisible}]
  \coordinate (calloutderposused) at ($(anchorderposused) +
  (0,1.5ex)$);

  \node[draw=orange, fill=orange!20, rectangle callout, rounded
  corners, callout absolute pointer=(calloutderposused)] at
  ($(anchorderposused)!0.8!(anchorderposhyp)$) {By hypothesis, because
    $]a;b[ \subset I$.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\textbf{Comments.} In short, all parts with a coloured line or dot
next to them are buttons that can be clicked to show (or hide) a more
detailed explanation of the assertion.

This is more a ``proof of concept'' than a real attempt at having an
hypertext proof. Especially, the proof has a lot of ``bells and
whistles'' that are probably useless. Moreover, various different ways
of indicating that an explanation exists are mixed and this is
probably not a good idea in general.

However, this shows that it is possible to have such added details to
a proof in a reasonable way. This can be useful in many academic
situations, including hiding solution of exercises in a textbook, or
preparing an article with both a short and a long version mixed
without resorting to appendices (that are often clumsy to navigate
back and forth).

Due to restrictions in \texttt{pdf} (or in my knowledge of it), it is
not possible to have the extra explanations ``push down'' the
following text when appearing. All the space for them must be reserved
in advance. This is why I chose to used multiple ``pop-ups'' to
display the explanations rather than having huge white gaps in the
text like the following (\switchocg{text}{\textcolor{red}{Click me!}})

\begin{ocg}{Hidden text}{text}{off}
  This is a hidden text (e.g., paragraph).
\end{ocg}

The typesetting and (especially) positioning of all this is currently
done manually (and somewhat painfully). 

\vdots

The manual positioning can be somewhat improved by using more relative
coordinates and the various ``\texttt{north east}'' and so on anchors
on Ti\emph{k}Z nodes, but this was not my main goal\ldots



\vspace{10cm}

\hspace{5cm} \jymanchor{toto}

% button
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (totosw) at ($(anchortoto) + (-1cm,-0.5cm)$);
  \coordinate (totone) at ($(anchortoto) + (1cm,0.5cm)$);
  \path[switch ocg={achievement}] (totosw) rectangle (totone);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Achievement,
    ref=achievement, status=invisible}]
  \node[starburst, draw, red,fill=yellow,line width=1.5pt, text
  width=5cm] at (anchortoto) {\begin{center} \textsc{\Large
        Achievement Unlocked!}\\
      Click in the middle of nowhere.\\
      \scriptsize \textcolor{orange}{Did you read the code to find
        me?}
  \end{center}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\section{Hypertext structured proof}
\begin{proof}[Hypertext structured proof]~\\[-.5cm]
  \begin{structproof}
    % Strange stuff happens if the anchor is placed before the 'It'
    % (it is actually placed at the very start of the proof, before
    % the first step). I assume strange behaviour of the \step
    % command.
    \step{1}{It\jymanchor{struct1} suffices to assume
      \begin{pfenum*}
      \item $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$\jymanchor{left1}
      \item $a < b$
      \end{pfenum*}
      and prove $f(b) > f(a)$.\jymanchor{struct1bis}
    }
    \step{2}{\switchocg{struct2 struct2proof}{\largeocghline{Structure
          2}{struct2}{off}{green!50}{There is some $x$ in $]a;b[$
          with $f'(x) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.}}\jymanchor{left2}}
    \step{3}{\switchocg{struct3}{\ocghline{Structure
          3}{struct3}{off}{red!50}{$f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in
          $]a;b[$.}}\jymanchor{left3}}
    \step{4}{\switchocg{struct4}{\largeocghline{Structure
          4}{struct4}{off}{blue!50}{$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} >
          0$.}}\jymanchor{left4}}
    \step{5}{\switchocg{struct5}{\ocghline{Structure
            5}{struct5}{off}{orange!50}{Q.E.D.}}\jymanchor{left5}}
      % should use \qedPfkwd
  \end{structproof}
\end{proof}

% button for 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (struct1nw) at ($(anchorstruct1) + (-2ex,2.3ex)$);
  \coordinate (struct1se) at ($(anchorstruct1bis) + (5.2ex,-0.5ex)$);
  \path[switch ocg={struct1hl}] (struct1nw) rectangle (struct1se);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Structure 1 HL,
    ref=struct1hl, status=invisible}]
  \fill[yellow, opacity=.3] (struct1nw) rectangle (struct1se);

  \node[draw=yellow, fill=yellow!20, rectangle, rounded corners] at
  ($(anchorleft1) + (3cm,2cm)$) {\pf\ By definition of an increasing
    function.};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Proof for 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Structure 2 Proof,
    ref=struct2proof, status=invisible}]
  \node[draw=green, fill=green!20, rectangle, rounded corners,
  text width=7cm] at ($(anchorleft2) + (4cm, 1.15cm)$) {%
    \begin{structproof}
      \nostep{no1}
      \nostep{no2}
      \begin{noproof}
        \step{2.1}{\switchocg{struct21}{$f$ is differentiable on
            $[a;b]$.}}
        \begin{ocg}{Structure 2.1}{struct21}{off}
          \begin{structproof}
            \pf\ By 1.1, since $f$ is differentiable on $I$ by
            hypothesis.
          \end{structproof}
        \end{ocg}
        \step{2.2}{\switchocg{struct22}{$f$ is continuous on
            $[a;b]$.}}
        \begin{ocg}{Structure 2.2}{struct22}{off}
          \begin{structproof}
            \pf\ By \stepref{2.1} and Theorem~\ref{thm:diff-cont}.
          \end{structproof}
        \end{ocg}
      % \qedstep is not easy to OCG-ise…
      % \qedstep
        \step{2.3}{\switchocg{struct23}{Q.E.D.}} % should use \qedPfkwd
        \begin{ocg}{Structure 2.3}{struct23}{off}
          \begin{structproof}
            \pf\ By \stepref{2.1}, \stepref{2.2}, and the Mean Value
            Theorem (Theorem~\ref{thm:mean-value}).
          \end{structproof}
        \end{ocg}
      \end{noproof}
    \end{structproof}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% Proof for 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Structure 3,
    ref=struct3, status=invisible}]

  \node[draw=red, fill=red!20, rectangle, rounded corners] at
  ($(anchorleft3) + (6cm,-0.6cm)$) {\pf\ By the hypothesis of the corollary
    and assumption 1.1.};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Proof for 4
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Structure 4,
    ref=struct4, status=invisible}]

  \node[draw=blue, fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners] at
  ($(anchorleft4) + (3cm,-0.7cm)$) {\pf\ By 2 and 3.};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Proof for 5
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Structure 5,
    ref=struct5, status=invisible}]

  \node[draw=orange, fill=orange!20, rectangle, rounded corners, text
  width=15cm] at ($(anchorleft5) + (6.8cm,-1.2cm)$) {\pf\ Assumption 1.2
    implies $b-a>0$, so 4 implies $f(b)-f(b) > 0$, which implies
    $f(b) > f(a)$. By 1, this proves the corollary.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-1.5cm}

\textbf{Comments.} The very good point about the structured hypertext
proof is that we can make use of the structure. On the reader point of
view, that means that every assumption (proof step) that is not proved
can be clicked to display its proof; there is no need to the somewhat
clumsy lines indicating ``details available'' in the prose proof. I
also find it easier to locate steps 2 and 3 when reading the proof of
step 4, because they are not interleaved with their proofs. On the
writer point of view, that means that the \verb+\step+ command of the
\texttt{pf2} package can be modified to automatically produce all the
needed buttons.

On the other hand, the structured proof might go into deeper level of
nesting of proofs. I do not imagine how it would be possible to
correctly lay out 4 or 6 nested levels of proof pop-ups. Well, likely
by actually not hiding all of them and considering that, say, the
first and second levels are the backbone of the proof, and should
always be displayed, and that the pop-ups should only start at the
third or so level\ldots

The other bad point, on a purely technical point of view, is that the
pop-ups are not part of the structured proof environment. That means
that commands like \verb+\stepref+ do not work. In this precise case,
I entered the number of the steps by hand but this is obviously not a
good idea. \verb+\pflabel+ and \verb+\pfref+ should be used
instead. However, on a ``logical structure'' point of view it is still
somewhat unsatisfactory that the subproofs are not really parts of the
proof.

On the good side, when both the statements and the proofs are short,
as this is the case here, the global positioning is easier with an
implicit splitting of the page in two.

\smallskip

This time, I chose to inline the proofs of the substeps 2.1, 2.2, and
2.3. I feel that because it is already part of a pop-up and because
they are short enough, the white space (well, green space, actually)
left when they are hidden is acceptable. Moreover, having separate
pop-ups for these would not have been easy to position without putting
them on top of the main step 2 itself and I do think that it is a bad
idea to prevent the reader from seeing both an assumption and its
complete proof.

I also chose not to add any ``callout'' pointers from the proof to the
assumption. I think that the differences in colours are sufficient to
avoid any mistake. Again, this is also a case display of what can be
done and how it looks like, hence it is good to have different layouts
to choose from.

Also, due to the shortness of the proofs, I was able to fan out all
the pop-ups without any covering another. This allows for a rather
nice result of the whole proof being visible if wanted.

\bigskip

As a closing word, I just want to mention that \switchocg{explul
  explhl}{\jymulhl{Explanations}{expl}{blue}{this technique is
    not\jymanchor{expl} restricted to proofs.}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Explanations HL,
    ref=explhl, status=invisible}]
  \coordinate (calloutexpl) at ($(anchorexpl) + (0,1.5ex)$);

  \node[draw=blue, fill=blue!20, rectangle callout, rounded corners,
  callout absolute pointer=(calloutexpl), text width=12cm] at
  ($(anchorexpl) + (-2cm,4cm)$) {Explanations in a running text can
    also be provided, for example, to detail some arguments in a
    discussion; or for parts of a text that are useful on the first
    read but can be omitted when rereading because they go into a lot
    of details to make a point but after being read once, one normally
    can remember the idea and do not need the wordy explanation
    again. Thus this technique is not restricted to sciences. It can
    also be used, taking example from some of my hobby fields, for:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \switchocg{history}{Writing history texts and have pop-ups
        recalling dates or details of events mentioned in the
        text.}\\
      \begin{ocg}{History}{history}{off}
        ``After \switchocg{bartul barthl}{\jymulhl{St
            Bartholomew}{bart}{red}{St Bartholomew's\jymanchor{bart}
            day massacre}}, French protestants went into hiding.''%
      \end{ocg}%
    \item \switchocg{rule}{Writing game rules and recall some rule
        when it is referenced.}\\
      \begin{ocg}{Rule}{rule}{off}
        ``A stack with no \switchocg{losul loshl}{\jymulhl{Line of
            Supply}{los}{pink}{Line of\,\jymanchor{los} Supply}} may not
        besiege.''
      \end{ocg}
    \end{itemize}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=St
    Bartholomew HL, ref=barthl, status=invisible}]
  \coordinate (calloutbart) at ($(anchorbart) + (0,1.5ex)$);

  \node[draw=red, fill=red!20, rectangle, rounded corners, text
  width=8cm] at ($(calloutbart) + (0,2.5cm)$) {\textbf{Wikipedia}: On
    the night of 23–24 August 1572, two days after the attempted
    assassination of Admiral Gaspard de Coligny, the military and
    political leader of the Huguenots. The king ordered the killing of
    a group of Huguenot leaders, including Coligny, and the slaughter
    spread throughout Paris. Lasting several weeks, the massacre
    expanded outward to other urban centres and the
    countryside. Modern estimates for the number of dead across France
    vary widely, from 5,000 to 30,000.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ocg={name=Line of
    Supply HL, ref=loshl, status=invisible}]
  \coordinate (calloutlos) at ($(anchorlos) + (0,1.5ex)$);

  \node[draw=pink, fill=pink!20, rectangle, rounded corners, text
  width=5cm] at ($(calloutbart) + (0,-3cm)$) {A Line of Supply goes
    from the Source of Supply to the stack and may not be more than
    12MP. See IX.7 for details.};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{thebibliography}{Lam12}
\bibitem[Lam12]{LamportProof}
Leslie Lamport.
\newblock How to write a 21st century proof.
\newblock {\em Journal of Fixed Point Theory and Applications}, March 2012.

\bibitem[Spi67]{Spivak}
Michael Spivak.
\newblock {\em Calculus}.
\newblock W. A. Benjamin, Inc., New York, 1967.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive example!

Comment: ..., but could be implemented more efficiently with fewer OCGs, using OCMDs (optional content membership dictionary), see the other answer.