# Click to reveal

Tags: minipage

I would like to make a split page (PDF), where the right hand side is only revealed after a click. I have no problem with the partitioning of the page, but I couldn't find a solution for the click to reveal part. Does anyone have a solution for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2

Comment: Recent example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668507

Comment: simplest would be to use `beamer` class which has an extensive mechanism for such gradual overlays and reveals.

Comment: Certain types of documents may call for the use of standard classes though, e. g. bilingual books with a continuous two-column layout.