# How to create a document with collapsible proofs?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ocg, ocgx2

I am trying to create a document which has a series of theorems and proofs, one right after the other. I would like it so that in the pdf, one can click a button next to a proof that collapses that proof. This would be convenient so that I can go through the document and see the overall flow of the theorems (without having a bunch of text for the proofs in between each theorem), but still see the proof of some given theorem by clicking on a button to expand it.

I believe I have to use the ogcx2 package. I have found a related solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596008/toggle-in-the-pdf), but it does not do quite what I want.
It only addresses items in a list, whereas I want to create a proof environment. Additionally, it seems to maintain the space related to the hidden text even if it is toggled off. For instance, if I add some text below, it will maintain the space in the pdf even if the hidden text is toggled off. Here is my code with the "More text":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathabx} % \blacktriangleright, \blacktriangledown

\usepackage{ocgx2}

% toggle switch with rotating item symbol; also defines Layer name and id
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemtoggle}{mm}{% #1 OCG name (as shown in Layer tab of the PDF viewer);
                                     % #2 internal identifier
  {\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}% suppresses link border around item if hyperref is loaded
  \switchocg{#2}{%           
    \begin{ocg}{#1}{#2}{off}\rlap{$\blacktriangledown$}\end{ocg}%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOff{#2}}$\blacktriangleright$\end{ocmd}%
  }}%
}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\hypersetup}{m}{}

\begin{document}
The relativity equation $E=mc^2$
\begin{itemize}
\item[\itemtoggle{Mass-Energy Equivalence}{emc2}] 
  {\color{cyan}%
  In physics, mass-energy equivalence is the relationship between mass and energy in a system's rest frame, where the two values differ only by a constant and the units of measurement. The principle is described by Albert Einstein's famous formula.}

  \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{emc2}}
  The formula defines the Energy ($E$) of a particle in its rest frame as the product of mass ($m$) and speed of light squared ($c^2$) \dots
  \end{ocmd}

   More text.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, this outputs the following in the PDF even when the emc2 text is hidden:
[image]

I would want it so that when the button is toggled off though, the "More text" appears directly beneath the blue text, without a gap. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the interaction you describe is more suited to html than pdf, as you can not  re-paginate as a large proof is hidden or revealed

Comment: Is there a way for latex to output an html then?

Comment: yes make4ht is in all the standard distributions or latexml or lwarp or ...

Comment: Thank you! And would you know how to make such a collapsible text using make4ht?